# Cannot manually install package in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I am trying to install package using:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("s-conner/rmtl/rpackage")
```

However, I got an error:

> Error: Failed to install 'RMTL' from GitHub:
> schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed

Any advise, please?

Comment: Try using remotes instead of devtools, `remotes::install_github("s-conner/rmtl/rpackage")`.

Comment: @jay.sf unfurtenately, does not function: 
library(remotes)
remotes::install_github("s-conner/rmtl/rpackage")
Error: Failed to install 'RMTL' from GitHub:
  schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed

Answer (score 0):

It installs fine for me (on Linux).  As the output shows, I also have a GITHUB_PAT but I do not think that should be required for a public repository.

```
$ installGithub.r s-conner/rmtl/rpackage
Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Downloading GitHub repo s-conner/rmtl@HEAD
── R CMD build ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/remotes16a2746ead7197/s-conner-rmtl-c2fb188/rpackage/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘rmtl’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Omitted ‘LazyData’ from DESCRIPTION
─  building ‘rmtl_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz’
   
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘rmtl’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (rmtl)
$
```

(where `installGithub.r` is a simple convenience wrapper for `remotes::install_github` from my [littler](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler) CRAN package.)

So I guess you need to work out why the https handshake to GitHub fails for you. It would seem that GitHub serves the repository just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can also source the 3 functions in the package at the start of your code

```
devtools::source_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-conner/rmtl/master/rpackage/R/cif.R")
devtools::source_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-conner/rmtl/master/rpackage/R/rmtl.R")
devtools::source_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-conner/rmtl/master/rpackage/R/rmtl_mod.R")
```

You can also download the 3 r scripts files and source them

```
source("path/to/rmtl.R")
```